# Smoother change between two materials using Mix Shader

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

It's not a problem to make a gradient changing, but I need a simple transition.

Let's say I want to mix two materials and change them one by one at some point in time.
If I just animate the factor from 0 to 1, materials change too sharply.

[image]

What should I connect to the factor to make the changing smoother?

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot of your object and Shader Editor?

Comment: Well, i made an easy example. 
The problem it starts switching already close to 1 (from 0.9) and not gradually. So it's not a smooth changing.
https://i.postimg.cc/KY1Tyhfm/zzz.jpg

Comment: Your link doesn't work, maybe share a file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Sure. Yuo're right. The strength of emission really affects the transition. Thanks. 
I knew the answer was simple and I just couldn't see it. )))

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann do you want to make a quick answer out of your fix? I've popped the image in, so it would be to the question actually asked.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It's only true if RusDark has changed the *Color Managment* to linear. But your point is correct, high emission reduces the transparent range.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It's wrong to say that Blender has a maximum color value (in rendered image) of 1. It's only true in *Standard* CM where values > 1 are displayed as 1 and clamped at 1 in rendered image. With it, any (10,0,10) color is rendered as (1,0,1) while loosing everything above 1. But for example with the default *AgX* CM, it maps any color (including (10,0,10)) to a suitable [0,1] range for displaying (while changing the saturation and brightness, photorealistically). So in *AgX* CM, emission (10,0,10) mixed at 90% transparency is actually (0.79, 0.46, 0.79) and not (1,0,1).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann An emission of (1,0,1) at strength 1 does *not* reach any limit (expect for *Standard* CM), as shown in the gradients in my answer. So your math is only correct for the non-default *Standard* color managment. I just wanted people to know you can't do basic math like that outside of *Standard* CM.

Answer (score 1):

### Control [0,1] range with *Power*

Because we're interested in a [0,1] range (currently your *Mix Shader* factor), we can easily tweak the curve using exponents. Which means we know our initial 0 will still be 0, and our initial 1 will also still be 1.

So, by adding a *Power* node between your initial [0,1] range and your *Mix Shader*, we can tweak the factor with only one parameter. Here is my setup, followed by some notes :

[image: Comparison of different exponents of 0 to 1 range]

- In my example, the *Exponent* isn't meaned to be animated, more as a way of finding a [0,1] curve that matches your need. But of course it could be animated as well. A low exponent (between 0 and 1) will counterbalance your high emission strength. Try 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 or even lower values.
- I've highlighted in *red* where would be the visual equivalent of magenta color (with an emission of 1). In your case, because of the emission strength of 10, you initially need to approach a high factor to feel the transparency.
- As you see with a low exponent, you compress the left part of the gradient and expand the right part, moving the middle point.
- Exponents are only one way of tweaking such curve. For example you could use a *Float Curve* node if you prefer a more graphical approach, or other mathematical functions.
- You could *Map Range* any another range of values [A,B] to the [0,1] range, pass it through the *Power* node, then again *Map Range* from [0,1] to [A,B]. It can be powerful to quickly change a distribution of values.

In your case the setup would simply be :

[image: Final setup]